# awk to extract value in each line and create new file

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to extract the value of a substring in each line, and the 2 attempts do not produce the desired results. The first awk executes and returns no data,
and the second only extracts the value. Thank you  :).

**file**

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1   930215  CM1613956   A   G   .   .   PHEN="Retinitis_pigmentosa";RANKSCORE=0.21
```

**awk 1**

```
awk '/^#/ {for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "RANKSCORE=") print $(I+1)}' file
```

**awk 2**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}; /^#/ {print $1,$2,$3} {sub(/.*RANKSCORE=/, ""); print}' file

#CHROM  POS     ID
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
0.21
0.99
```

**desired** (tab-delimited)

```
1   930215  CM1613956   A   G   .   .   0.21
```

Comment: `$I` will never equal `"RANKSCORE="` because $I is splitting columns by the default whitespace. $I will equal `PHEN="Retinities_pigmentosa";RANKSCORE=0.21` You will likely need some regex instead like `$I ~ /RANKSCORE/` or something. At that point you will be at NF so there will be no `$(I+1)` to print (you are at the end of the line).

Comment: Also your `/^#/` is only going to match the first row (your header). I think you want `/^[^#]/` instead.

Comment: You could consider something like `awk -F"[;=]" '/^[^#]/ {for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "RANKSCORE") print $(I+1)}'` which is close to your original attempt. The addition of -F"[;=]" tells awk to split the columns on semicolons and equal signs so your for loop and search works (with some small changes)

Comment: Out of curiosity, given your desired results, is this RANKSCORE alwaysgoing to appear in your last column/INFO column?

Comment: RANKSCORE will always be in the last column (INFO).  Thank you :).

Comment: Will RANKSCORE always be the last `=` in INFO or could it appear anywhere in INFO column?

Comment: In this case in will always be the last `=`. Thank you :).

Comment: are you fields delimited by spaces or tabs? can the last field (`INFO`) contain spaces or tabs? can any of the other fields contain spaces or tabs?

Comment: The fields are delimited by tabs and within each field there are no spaces or tabs.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no arrays needed :

> ```
> {m,n,g}awk '!+_<+NF && sub(";.*$", _, $(NF=NF))^_'\
>             FS='[ \t]+([^ \t]*;)?RANKSCORE='  OFS='\t'
> ```

```
1   930215  CM1613956   A   G   .   .   0.21
1   930215  CM1613956   A   G   .   .   3.235
1   930215  CM1613956   A   G   .   .   9.3325
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
/^#/ {next}
$NF ~ /;RANKSCORE=/ {
   sub(/.+=/, "", $NF)
} 1' file

1   930215  CM1613956   A   G   .   .   0.21
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -F';RANKSCORE=' '
BEGIN{ OFS ="\t" }
/^#/ { next      }
NF==2 && match($0,/.* /){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),$2
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -F';RANKSCORE=' '      ##Starting awk program from here, settings field separator as ;RANKSCORE=
BEGIN{ OFS ="\t" }         ##Setting OFS as tab in BEGIN section of this code.
/^#/ { next      }         ##If a line starts from # then simply skip that line.
NF==2 && match($0,/.* /){  ##Check if NF is 2 AND matching till last occurrence of single space.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),$2 ##Printing sub string till matched regex along with 2md field.
}
'  Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RANKSCORE seems to appear in field 8.

`match` can locate it. `substr` can extract it.

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    match($8,/RANKSCORE=[0-9.]+/){
        $8 = substr($8, RSTART+10, RLENGTH-10)
        print
    }
' file
```

Or more safely, assuming semi-colon sub-delimiters, a couple of `subs`:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    sub(/^(.*;)?RANKSCORE=/,"",$8){
        sub(/[^0-9.].*$/,"",$8)
        print
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- we only want exact word matches on `RANKSCORE` (eg, do not match on `old_RANKSCORE`)
- `RANKSCORE=value` could show up anywhere in a `;`-delimited last field

Adding some lines with different locations of `RANKSCORE`:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1       930215  CM1613956       A       G       .       .       PHEN="Retinitis_pigmentosa";RANKSCORE=0.21
1       930215  CM1613956       A       G       .       .       RANKSCORE=3.235;PHEN="Retinitis_pigmentosa"
1       930215  CM1613956       A       G       .       .       stuff=123;old_RANKSCORE=7.7234;PHEN="Retinitis_pigmentosa"
1       930215  CM1613956       A       G       .       .       stuff=123;RANKSCORE=9.3325;PHEN="Retinitis_pigmentosa"
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN       { FS=OFS="\t" }
/RANKSCORE/ { n=split($NF,a,"[;=]")            # if line contains "RANKSCORE" then split last field on dual delimiters ";" and "="
              for (i=1;i<=n;i=i+2)             # loop through attribute names (odd-numbered indices) and ...
                  if (a[i] == "RANKSCORE") {   # if attribute == "RANKSCORE" then ...
                     $NF=a[i+1]                # use associated value (even-numbered index) as new value for last field
                     print                     # print new line
                     next                      # go to next input line
                  }
            }
' file
```

This generates:

```
1       930215  CM1613956       A       G       .       .       0.21
1       930215  CM1613956       A       G       .       .       3.235
1       930215  CM1613956       A       G       .       .       9.3325
```